# onclick not working in internet explorer 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have the following code on a webpage:

```
<DIV style="TEXT-ALIGN: center">
<A style="CURSOR: auto" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" onmouseout="this.style.cursor='auto'" onclick="alert('0: 272ec6651cb6d320579205b7a250a14920708a41');">[Back To List]</A>
<A onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" onmouseout="this.style.cursor='auto'" onclick="alert('1: 20');">[View Comments]</A>
</DIV>
```

The first link works, the second one doesn't. By works, I mean that the pointer changes on mouseover, and clicking it triggers the alert message. The second link, the mouse doesn't change, and clicking it does nothing. What have I done wrong here? How do I make this work?

Also note, that this works fine in firefox, google chrome, and internet explorer 8 - it's only internet explorer 7 and below that have a problem with it, but I do need to support them.

**Edit:** To clarify, *nothing* about the second link is working - it's not just the javascript, the mouseover is also not changing the mouse pointer like it does for the first. There's obviously something about the first link that is causing ie to not process the second properly, but I can't see what it could be.

Comment: Strange.Works on my IE 7

Comment: view the page source to know all attributes of your anchor tag

Comment: did u try with capital C ( for ie 7) 'onClick'

Comment: Why are you changing the cursor on mouseover/mouseout? It shouldn't make any difference if you set it always to pointer

Comment: @diEcho why would that make only the first link work?

Comment: @diEcho no, that didn't help.

Comment: Why are you capitalising HMTL and CSS, this isn't the 90's all lower case tags...

Comment: @Myles because this is dynamically generated using document.createElement, and I've copied and pasted it from the view source, so this is how internet explorer sees it.

Answer (score 1):

try using developer tools in IE to find your second link's position in IE7. May be it's not in where you think it should be.

Comment: Actually I copied this from the developer tools; the links themselves are being generated by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You might try prefixing the `onclick` with `javascript:` like so:

```
<A onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" onmouseout="this.style.cursor='auto'" onclick="javascript:alert('1: 20');">[View Comments]</A>
```

Could it be possible that your IE7 is blocking alerts?  Maybe change it from an alert to some user defined function or evening change the cursor style as you have done for the mouseover just to test.

Comment: adding javascript: didn't help.

Comment: In the context of JavaScript code, `javascript:' is a label. In this case, it serves no purpose. It's like adding 'foobar:' to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I copy/paste your code in my page and opened it with IE7, no problem at all with cursors nor links.

I tried with/without Quircks mode and both worked. You may have something else in the page that is interfering?

My IE version : 7.0.6001.18000

Comment: Yeah, sorry I mistyped it into the question; there shouldn't be a space between the final closing a tag and the closing div tag.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for it. It's not actually visible in the original question (sorry!) but the second link ended with `</A></DIV>`. I added a space, to make it `</A> </DIV>` and it works now.

I've pretty much given up on internet explorer making sense, but this is exceptionally bewildering. So if anyone can tell me why I needed that extra space I'd appreciate it (and mark your answer correct).

Comment: Hummm are you sure you didn't modify anything else? Because you're right it doesn't make sense and surely is not the cause of your problem (Still works on my IE7). I would be glad if you could send the whole **Wrong** code just for my own culture.

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue Can't, sorry - NDA

Comment: Caching issue, I'm betting. Shift-clicking-refresh is the simplest way to fix that sort of thing